# Angular Reactive form is validating for all iterations

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using `reactive forms` inside `*ngFor` for validations in my application. But when I'm trying to validate only for one iteration, the form is being validated in all the iterations.

I tried using template driven form and it's working good. But I want to learn it using reactive forms.

Below is my code

HTML

```
<div *ngFor = "let f of flowers">
<div>{{f.type}} </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label>Flower License</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="fLicense" [class.invalid]="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched ">
  <div *ngIf="!statusForm.controls['fLicense'].valid && (statusForm.controls['fLicense'].touched || isSubmitted)">
    <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;">Please enter flower License Number</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.statusForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    fLicense: ['', Validators.required],
  });
}

submitStatus(f) {
  this.isSubmitted = true;
  // stop here if form is invalid
  if (this.statusForm.invalid) {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because Form has no idea about the *ngFor iteration it has only single instance as of now

Comment: @PardeepJain How can we achieve this? Any leads?

Comment: You have to create array of FormControl using flowers data

Comment: you can think of creating form Array instead of Form group that might does trick for you.

Comment: @Chellappanவ Thanks. I will be checking it. No idea about that. Still in learning stage